# Java inheritance: upcasting a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, upcasting

I have read documentation and other questions, but there are cases of upcasting that really puzzle me.

I have this example, while the first 3 cases are quite straightforward after a bit of thinking, the last 4 leave me confused.

There is clearly something about casting that I do not understand.

```
class A {
    public static   void p (Object o)   { System.out.println(o); }
    public          void m1 (A a)       { p("m1(A) in A"); }
    public          void m1 ()          { m1(new B());}
    public          void m2 (A a)       { p("m2(A) in A");}
    public          void m2 ()          { m2(this);}
    public          void m3 (B b)       { m2(this); }
}

class B extends A {
    public          void m1 (B b)       { p("m1(B) in B");}
    public          void m2 (A a)       { p("m2(A) in B");}
    public          void m2 (B b)       { p("m2(B) in B");}
    public          void m3 (B b)       { super.m1(b);}
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B(); // Instance of class B casted to A
        B b = new B(); // Instance of class B

        // 1. prints "m1(A) in A"
        b.m1();

        // 2. prints "m2(A) in B"
        b.m2();

        // 3. prints "m2(A) in B"
        a.m2();

        // 4. prints "m1(A) in A"
        a.m3((B)a);
    }
}
```

Example 1:

I'd expect here `m1(B) in B` to be printed.

B inherits A, and since there is no `B.m1()`, it calls `A.m1()` which calls `m1(B)`. Since we are calling from B, why does it calls `A.m1(B)` and not `B.m1(B)`?

I expect A.m1()->B.m1(A), not A.m1()->A.m1(B)

Example 2:

Since 4 gives `"m1(A) in A"`, I'd expect the same thing here, since the flow seems the same to me.

Just looking to example 1, I expect A.m2()->A.m2(A), not A.m2()->B.m2(A)

Example 3:

`bb.m2();` prints `m2(A) in B`.

I'd expect `m2(A) in A`, since a it is casted to `A`. Why does it call `B.m2(A)`?

Example 4.

It calls `B.m3()`, also if it casted to `A`. Why? I'd expect it to call `A.m3()`, since it has been casted

Comment: can you be more specific in your question itself what it is you are confused about, and why? not just in comments in the code.

Comment: @Stultuske you are right, I added questions also separately, trying to explain them a bit more

Comment: This is long and a bit hard to follow. I recommend you remove all the stuff that you already understand and only leave the parts of the code that you want explained, along with a little bit of your own reasoning. Aside from that you're asking pretty good questions.

Comment: @CoffeeNinja done, simplified and tried to make it a more clear

Comment: This is an excellent question about things that are easy to misunderstand about inheritance. For example the only submitted (and upvoted answer) below is wrong. And although I wrote another answer I can't submit because it was very quickly put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1:** The call of `m1(new B());` is inside class `A`. `A` does not know any implementation details of subclasses (e.g. that of `B`), so it only knows of `A.m1(A)`.
**Example 2:** You can add a simple `System.out.println(this.getClass());` to show the class of `this`. It will show you that the type of `this` is `$B`. You have called the method on `B` and `B` knows of that method `m2(B b)` so that one is called.
**Example 3:** Same reason as 5.
**Example 4:** It is called `B.m3()` which in turn calls `super.m1(b);`. This calls the super method `A.m1(A a)` because `B` extends `A`. It cannot call `B.m1(B b)` because of the explicit call on `super`. If there is no method in `A` which is sufficient, you would get a compiler error.

**UPDATE**

Difference between **Example 1** and **Example 2**:
In **Example 1** `b.m1();` is calling the method `m1()` of class `A`. Because in the moment `m1()` is called, the compiler does only know that the type is `A` and not `B`. Let's say you would only see a variable of type `A` then you can only see the methods of `A`. Because of this the subsequent call of `m1(new B());` results in the call of the method of `A`. There is no `B` availabe for the compiler to call methods of it.
In **Example 2** is the variable `b` of type `B`, so the compiler can see all methods of `A` and all methods of `B`. Because of this the compiler knows about the method `B.m2(B b)` and can call it in the subsequent call of `m2(this)`.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get the difference between 4. and 5. How do I know that 4 is called inside class A, while 5 and 6 are inside class B?

Comment: While m1(new B()) is indeed called inside class A, overriden methods of B will still be preferred instead of original methods of A. The type of `this` inside A.m1() is actually B (in example 1)